# Error while installing pygame for python 3.4.3 on 64-bit system

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pygame

Since I am running a 64 bit version of Windows 7, I installed the pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame. I extracted the .whl file and placed everything in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages

I keep getting the error shown in this screenshot:
http://puu.sh/hwIUW/5b89f90415.png

What does this error mean? How do I get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame installation for python 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562933/pygame-installation-for-python-3-5)

Comment: The error screenshot link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install that `.whl` file using `pip`. Check out the answers to this similar question [Pygame installation for python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562933/pygame-installation-for-python-3-5/36563069?noredirect=1#)

Comment: Then this question should have been flagged as duplicate (of the similar question you linked)