# Pygame installation for python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pygame, failed-installation

I cannot repeat the instructions to install Pygame for some reason. Instructions are from this website:
https://skellykiernan.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/python-pygame-install/

I downloaded the most recent binary:

```
pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none.win32.whl
```

I placed this `.whl` file into the Scripts folder and opened a command window there. Then, following the instructions from the blog above (rather than the instructions from my book, "Python Crash Course," which were next to useless), I typed in the following:

```
pip3 install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none.win32.whl
```

What I get back is:

```
pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What am I doing wrong, or is there another, better way to install Pygame for Python 3.5?

Comment: Pygame is notoriously difficult to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using 64 bit python version. The pygame you are trying to install is for 32 bit version of python. You should try downloading the 64 bits version [`pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)

Comment: I attempted to use that .whl, but get a different message back now: "Requirement already satisfied" Still, when I attempt to import pygame, the traceback tells me that there is no such module. I can actually see a folder called "pygame" in my Python directory. It's under  Python\Python35\include... but how do I connect it to the Python interpreter so I can actually use it?

Comment: If you are using multiple environments, You can install the pygame in the active environment by this code `pip3 -E yourActiveEnvironmentName -I  pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`. If you are working in the root environment, just use `pip3 -I  pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` then `pip3 install pygame --upgrade`. The *I* option forces pip to ignore installed pygame.

Comment: This ended up being exactly the answer for my problem, but for some strange reason it only worked after I regressed back to Python 3.4, and used the appropriate pygame .whl file for that version. Why would it work then, and not with 3.5... the world may never know.